# Slow Scroll jittery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this code: [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wyx3o6uy/49/)

Depending on if "image-ul" is fully above the bottom edge of the browser window or not, will make divs scroll at different speeds, as it should. But the problem that I am having is that the scrolling is not smooth when the slow scrolling divs get somewhere close to the top of the page. They seem to stall for a moment, and even scroll in the opposite direction sometimes.

```
    //
// default speed ist the lowest valid scroll speed.
//
var default_speed = 1;
//
// speed increments defines the increase/decrease of the acceleration
// between current scroll speed and data-scroll-speed
//
var speed_increment = 0.01;
//
// maximum scroll speed of the elements
//
var data_scroll_speed_a = 3; // #sloganenglish
var data_scroll_speed_b = 5; // #image-ul
//
//
//
var increase_speed, decrease_speed, target_speed, current_speed, speed_increments;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {
        var WindowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
            Div_one_top = $('#image-ul').offset().top,
            Div_one_height = $('#image-ul').outerHeight(true),
            Window_height = $(this).outerHeight(true);
        if (WindowScrollTop + Window_height >= (Div_one_top + Div_one_height)) {
            $('#sloganenglish').attr('data-scroll-speed', data_scroll_speed_a).attr('data-current-scroll-speed', default_speed).attr('data-speed-increments', data_scroll_speed_a * speed_increment);
            $('#image-ul').attr('data-scroll-speed', data_scroll_speed_b).attr('data-current-scroll-speed', default_speed).attr('data-speed-increments', data_scroll_speed_b * speed_increment);
            $('.slogan-a-line').css('color', 'yellow');
            increase_speed = true;
            decrease_speed = false;
        } else {
            $('#sloganenglish').attr('data-scroll-speed', '1').attr('data-current-scroll-speed', default_speed);
            $('#image-ul').attr('data-scroll-speed', '1').attr('data-current-scroll-speed', default_speed);
            $('.slogan-a-line').css('color', 'red');
            decrease_speed = true;
            increase_speed = false;
        }
    }).scroll();
});


// data-scroll-speed script
$.fn.moveIt = function() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var instances = [];

    $(this).each(function() {
        instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
    });

    window.onscroll = function() {
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        instances.forEach(function(inst) {
            inst.update(scrollTop);
        });
    }
}

var moveItItem = function(el) {
    this.el = $(el);
    this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
    this.current_speed = 1.0;
};

moveItItem.prototype.update = function(scrollTop) {

    target_speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
    current_speed = this.current_speed;
    speed_increments = parseFloat(this.el.attr('data-speed-increments'));

    if (increase_speed) {
        if (current_speed < target_speed) {
            current_speed += speed_increments;
        } else {
            current_speed = target_speed;
        }
    } else if (decrease_speed) {
        if (current_speed > default_speed) {
            current_speed -= speed_increments;
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
            current_speed = default_speed;
        }
    }
    this.current_speed = current_speed;
    var pos = scrollTop / this.current_speed;
    this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -pos + 'px)');
};

// Initialization
$(function() {
    $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample code wasn't slow for me, so it may be specific to your machine or browser.

However, there are a few things you can do:

1. Don't use jQuery where you don't need it. jQuery is *significantly* slower than using native JS functions (e.g. `document.getElementById`).
2. Don't repeatedly use jQuery selectors. Every time you use a jQuery selector, you suffer a performance hit. So for example, instead of this:

   ```
   function(){
       var Div_one_top = $('#image-ul').offset().top,
       Div_one_height = $('#image-ul').outerHeight(true);
   }
   ```

Do this:

```
var imageUl = $('#image-ul');
function(){
     imageUl.offset().top,
     imageUl.outerHeight(true);
}
```

This example should increase performance quite a bit. You're doing multiple jQuery selectors every time the page scrolls for no reason.

The best choice for something performance intensive is to cut out jQuery completely and do it by hand.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Christopher Schneider!! However, that seems like a total re-code I am not code-smart enough for.

Comment: Well, removing jQuery is. However, at the very least you should move your jQuery selectors outside of the function.